# R aggregating a column values into rows

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to get some help with summarizing a dataframe.

My example df looks like this:

```
ID           Zoo            Last_date
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Oct_2017
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Oct_2017
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
HG-IJK      MEMPHIS         Jan_2018
JK-LMO      MEMPHIS         Feb_2018
```

The result should be

```
ID          ZOO          Oct_2017  Nov_2017 Jan_2019  Feb_2018
ABC-DEF    DENVER          2         3         0           0
HG-IJK      MEMPHIS        0         0         1           0
JK-LMO      MEMPHIS        0         0         0           1
```

I tried looking at `reshape2` using the `melt` and `cast` functions but I couldn't achieve the desired result. 
I melted the data into long form

```
tempMelt <- melt(temp, id.vars = 1:2, na.rm = FALSE)
```

and cast using

```
casttemp <- dcast(aqm, "ID" + "Zoo" ~ value)
```

Comment: Check group_by and summarise of the dplyr package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape2) # or you could use data.table's dcast function
dcast(df, ID + Zoo ~ Last_date)

#        ID     Zoo Feb_2018 Jan_2018 Nov_2017 Oct_2017
# 1 ABC-DEF  DENVER        0        0        3        2
# 2  HG-IJK MEMPHIS        0        1        0        0
# 3  JK-LMO MEMPHIS        1        0        0        0
```

This gives a warning about not specifying the value var or aggregation function. You can be a little more verbose to avoid the warning

```
dcast(df, ID + Zoo ~ Last_date, value.var = 'Last_date', length)
```

Data used

```
df <- data.table::fread("
ID           Zoo            Last_date
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Oct_2017
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Oct_2017
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
ABC-DEF     DENVER          Nov_2017  
HG-IJK      MEMPHIS         Jan_2018
JK-LMO      MEMPHIS         Feb_2018
")
```